# Is this idiomatic use of Text.Parsec?

Tags: haskell, parsec

My use of `Text.Parsec` is a little rusty.  If I just want to return the matched string is this idiomatic?

```
category :: Stream s m Char => ParsecT s u m [Char]                        
category = concat <$> (many1 $ (:) <$> char '/' <*> (many1 $ noneOf "/\n"))
```

I feel like there might be an existing operator for `liftM concat . many1` or `(:) <$> p1 <*> p2` that I'm ignoring, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's fine, I think. A little judicious naming would make it prettier:

```
category = concat <$> many1 segment
  where
    segment = (:) <$> char '/' <*> many1 (noneOf "/\n")
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it would be *slightly* more idiomatic use of Parsec to return something more structured, for example, the list of strings:

```
catList :: Parser [String]    
catList = char '/' *> many1 alphaNum `sepBy1` char '/'
```

I don't think there's a combinator like the one you were wondering there was, but this is Haskell, and roll-your-own-control-structure-or-combinator is always available:

```
concatMany1 :: Parser [a] -> Parser [a]
concatMany1 p = concat <$> many1 p

catConcat = concatMany1 $ (:) <$> char '/' <*> many1 alphaNum
```

But this next combinator is even nicer, and definitely idiomatic Haskell at least:

```
infixr 5 <:>
(<:>) :: Applicative f => f a -> f [a] -> f [a]
hd <:> tl = (:) <$> hd <*> tl
```

So now we can write

```
catCons :: Parser String
catCons = concatMany1 (char '/' <:> many1 alphaNum)
```

but incidentally also

```
contrivedExample :: IO String
contrivedExample = getChar <:> getLine

moreContrived :: String -> Maybe String
moreContrived name = find isLetter name <:> lookup name symbolTable
```

### noneOf

You'll notice I've used `alphaNum` where you used `noneOf "/\n"`. I think `noneOf` is not good practice; parsers should be really careful to accept onlt the right thing. Are you absolutely sure you want your parser to accept `/qwerty/12345/!"£$%^&*()@:?><.,#{}[]    \/  "/" /-=_+~`? Should it really be happy with `/usr\local\bin`?

As it stands, your parser accepts any string as long as it starts with `/` and ends before `\n` with something that's not `/`. I think you should rewrite it with `alphaNum <|> oneOf "_-.',~+"` or similar instead of using `noneOf`. Using `noneOf` allows you to avoid thinking about what you should allow and focus on getting positive examples to parse instead of *only* positive examples to parse.

### Parser

I've also always gone for `Parser a` instead of `Stream s m t => ParsecT s u m a`. That's just lazy typing, but let's pretend I did it to make it clearer what my code was doing, shall we? :)  Use what type signature suits you, of course.

Comment: (1) I want the complete string (not a list of strings), b/c I just need the path. I'll be using it as a hash key and then printing it (as a path) so keeping it in the proper format the whole time makes sense to me. (2) Does `alphaNum` deal well with non-ascii? I'll be dealing with lots of characters from non-english codepages. (3) Another reason I used `noneOf` is that I don't know that some categories don't include spaces or symbols.  I've got over a million of them, and this file that I'm parsing contains my first complete list of them, each on a line alone. So `noneOf "/\n"` seemed safe.

Comment: `alphaNum` seems to reduce to [`iswalnum`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/iswalnum.3.html), so I'll check that.

Comment: @rampion My point is that currently by using `noneOf`, the parser is equivalent to the line check `okLine xs = not (null xs) && head xs == '/'`, but runs slower because it chops at any `/` then recombines.